# Pusher not updating in realtime with laravel echo, laravel and vue js chat application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-7

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7r4s3kS5ItM) to learn build real-time chat application with Laravel, Vue js, Laravel Echo and Pusher js.

I've set my `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` in env and set pusher id, key, secret and cluster correctly.

Pusher config in `bootstrap.js`:

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});
```

Snippet from `app/Events/NewMessage.php`:

```js
use App\Message;
class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('messages.' . $this->message->to);
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->message];
    }
   }
```

Code snippet from controller

```js
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $message = Message::create([
            'from' => auth()->id(),
            'to' => $request->contact_id,
            'message' => $request->text
        ]);

        broadcast(new NewMessage($message));

        return response()->json($message);
    }
```

Code from main vue component that handels the event:

```js
    methods: {
        saveNewMessage(text) {
            this.loadMessages.push(text);
        },
        handelIncoming(message) {
            if (
                this.selectedContact &&
                message.from == this.selectedContact.id
            ) {
                this.saveNewMessage(message);
                return;
            }
            alert(message.text);
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`).listen("NewMessage", e => {
            this.hanleIncoming(e.message);
        });
        axios.get("/contacts").then(response => {
            this.contacts = response.data;
        });
    }
```

Code from channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

With the above code I can send and receive the message but not in real-time I have to reload the page or click the component again.

I've also checked the comment section in the video, many people were having same issues. Some of them had suggested to clear cache.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages, cleared cache, dump-autoload but still the same result.

The tutorial was made 2 years back and I'm doing it now on the latest laravel, pusher, echo versions. Has there been drastic changes in the applications that they don't run on old methods ?

Comment: Are you able to use the Pusher debug console (log in to dashboard.pusher.com, click your app and select the Debug Console tab) to verify that you are subscribing to the channel successfully, and that you are triggering events to the correct channel? Could you post a screenshot of the debug console with a subscribe and a trigger event captured?

Comment: Yes I can see events in the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that this event is fire and add to queue and you must run command
`queue:work`
to run.
is better to use `ShouldBroadcastNow` to fire your event immediately.